# Contribution Pages Required?

Tags: personal-campaign-pages

Does anyone happen to know how to get around having to set up a "Personal Campaign Page" - when making a "Contribution Page" (Our hope was to use a Contribution Page to collect donations via our Website.., We don't need Personal Campaign Pages, to do that.

I can't proceed without sending up a Personal Campaign Pages for some reason?

Comment: Personal Campaign Pages are not required. What versipn of CiviCRM is this?

Comment: Agreed with Karin. When you say it's required, is there a specific message that appears?